# Copy from clipboard data using javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, clipboarddata

I want to use the clipboard data so that I can copy and display the copied data in some html format. Using the "window.clipboardData" I can do this for Internet Explorer and using "event.clipboard" I can somehow solve this problem for Chrome and Safari. I'm still not able to find a fix for Firefox. Any help or suggestion will highly be appreciated.

I don't want to use any plugin or flash object. However a solution in jQuery is equally acceptable.

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript there is no way to do that in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't allow access to the clipboard because of understandable security reasons.